# Add to dictionary results from WaitAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to store results of async running tasks in private dictionary. When I use add, I've got a null reference exception. What should I change to properly fill the dictionary?

Here is my code, that I got so far:

```
 private Dictionary<string, long> _filesDictionary;

public void GetFiles(string pathToFolder)
{
    var allDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(pathToFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   allDirectories.ToList().Add(pathToFolder);
   foreach (var dir in allDirectories)
    {
        FolderReading(dir);

    }
}

public void FolderReading(string folderPath)
{
    string[] fileSystemEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath);
    if (fileSystemEntries.Count() != 0)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var filePath in fileSystemEntries.OrderBy(s => s))
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(() => CountSizes(filePath));
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}

private void CountSizes(string filePath)
{
    byte[] fileData = null;
    int arraySum = 0;
    string fileName = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        }
    }
    foreach (byte b in fileData)
    {
        arraySum += b;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{fileName} ArraySum{arraySum}; ThreadNum:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    _filesDictionary.Add(fileName, arraySum);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `_filesDictionary` is never *instantiated*, only declared, meaning it will always have the default value, in this case `null`. Somewhere in your code you need to assign it a value. Normally this is done in the constructor of a class, but you can also do it straight at the declaration.

Constructor:

```cs
_filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

Declaration:

```cs
private Dictionary<string, long> _filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

---

**Edit:** Just now noticed you're using multiple tasks to add to the dictionary, but beware that the defualt `Dictionary` is not entirely thread safe. Meaning, reading from a dictionary from multiple tasks (possibly on different threads of execution) is ok, but writing to it is not as it can lead to data races and invalid adds. Instead, you'll need to use .NET's [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)